# checking whether variable is not None and is a dict containing specific key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently find myself to write a few times code like

```
if myDict is not None:
    if 'thisKey' in myDict:
        variable = myDict['thisKey']
```

where I first check whether `myDict` is defined and then access the key, if it is defined. Is there a shortcut or more pythonic way for these kinds of tests?

I'm mostly looking to combine the two if clauses; I'm aware I didn't (yet) make use of the get methode, e.g. like `variable = myDict.get('thisKey')`, so it can be simplified / shortened to

```
if myDict is not None:
    variable = myDict.get('thisKey')
```

Yet, can it be made more concise / easier? Querying 'None' for a key raises an error.

We can safely assume for this purpose here that the variable WILL be a dict, if it is defined at all.

Comment: What is `variable` before? Can we make it `None` or `False` or something like that? `variable = myDict and myDict.get('thisKey')` should set it to `False` if undefined, `None` if key not in dict, and the value that you want otherwise.

Comment: The value of 'variable' is not defined before or its existing value is meaningless (previous loop iteration).

Comment: What value should `variable` get when `myDict` is `None`?

Comment: it should also be 'None'. Any numeric value or list would be problematic (as that could be a valid return value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying the common case and catching the exception is usually [considered more pythonic](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/06/29/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/) than explicitly testing for rare corner cases first:

```
try:
    variable = myDict.get('thisKey')
except AttributeError:  # when myDict is None
    variable = None
```

This is not shorter, but in my opinion this is clearer than trying to cram things into one line. If you are repeating these lines many times, you could write a small function:

```
def my_get(dictionary, key, default=None):
    """lookup key in dictionary. Returns default
    when key is missing or dictionary is None"""
    try:
        return dictionary.get(key, default)
    except AttributeError:  # when dictionary is None
        return default
```

Quick test:

```
In [19]: myDict = None
In [20]: my_get(myDict, 'key', 5)
Out[20]: 5

In [21]: myDict = {}
In [22]: my_get(myDict, 'key', 5)
Out[22]: 5

In [23]: myDict = dict(key=66)
In [24]: my_get(myDict, 'key', 5)
Out[24]: 66
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like these ?

```
if myDict and 'thisKey' in myDict:
    variable = myDict['thisKey']
```

or

```
variable = myDict.get('thisKey', None) if myDict else None
```

Comment: The second option raises an error when `myDict` is `None`

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [default dictionaries](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/using-defaultdict-python/), they allow you to set default values so your dictionary doesn't throw an exception if you try to access an unexisting key.